# Creating a List Specification in Alloy Language

Tags: list, alloy

I'm working on defining a List in Alloy but I'm stuck.

This is what I have so far (it acts like a LinkedList):

```
module List

// The List signature
lone sig List { rootElement: lone Element } 

// A list element signature
sig Element { nextElement: lone Element }


// Prevents an Element from referencing itself
fact preventElementLooping {
    no ele: Element | ele = ele.nextElement
}

// Zero Element outliers
fact allElementsBelongToOneList {
    all ele: Element | one list: List | ele in list.rootElement.*nextElement
}

// Prevents Elements from referencing a Element before it in the List
fact preventCycle {
    no ele: Element | ele in ele.^nextElement
}
```

This all looks good to me and I feel like this is correct.
I'm trying to define 3 predicates for this list definition:

- Create: Should create an empty list
- Put: Should add an item to the end of the list
- Find: Should return all indices in the list that match a given element

```
pred create(list, list":List) {
    list".rootElement = none    
}

pred put(list, list":List, ele: Element) {
    list".rootElement = ele
}

pred find [list:List, ele: Element] {
    ele = list.rootElement or ele in list.rootElement.^nextElement
}
```

This is what I need help with I feel like I'm missing something in those 3 preds.

**My questions:**

- Am I over complicating things by trying to use a linked list? How would you just do a normal list?
- Put is correct for the first put but fails when you need to put again as it just replaces the root element
- Find is the big struggle. I need to store the indices somewhere to return them right? Also I thought alloy only had bare bones understanding of Numbers for indexes (I believe only allowing -7 to 8). Should index be its own signature?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to define a notion of list in Alloy, yours is a possibility, depending no what you expect to do then.

I don't see why you want to make `List` a `lone` sig?

Another remark is that your list doesn't contain any data, only "elements" (I would call them cells), perhaps because it's of no use in your spec? Anyhow, you could make your module generic and store data in cells, e.g.:

```
module List[Data]
sig List { rootElement: lone Element } 
sig Element { data: one Data, nextElement: lone Element }
```

Your facts can also be improved:

1. By having only one fact rejecting all forms of cycles.
2. By only asking for elements to belong to *some* list rather than exactly one.

Finally, regarding operations, I suggest you take a look at how the standard library models lists and operations:

1. `util/seqrel` specifies lists as relations
2. `util/sequence` specifies lists as signatures holding elements
3. `util/sequniv` is like `util/seqrel` but relies on builtin integer indices and is implemented in an ad hoc concrete syntax based on the `seq` keyword.